# Use of "on to" versus "onto"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the following, if any, is correct?

1. "Thank you for holding on to me when I did not want to hold on to anyone."
2. "Thank you for holding onto me when I did not want to hold onto anyone."

Answer (score 4):

Generally, when you are using the preposition "in" or "on" with "to" there is a rule of thumb to follow:

> You use into [or onto] to say where someone or something goes, or where something is put.
> [Abused, Confused, & Misused Words](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/into)

We can break this down a bit further.

1. If "to" is followed by a noun location (e.g., table, box, room) you can combine the prepositions: *onto* the table, *into a box*, *into the room*. Example:

> I placed the book onto the table.

2. If "to" is part of an infinitive verb, use the split form. Example:

> Arriving at my sister's room, I went in to find her weeping.

but be careful if you change the word order:

> I went into my sister's room to find her weeping.

**addendum**

A commenter below believes "Onto victory!" is an exception to what I say here, but I will only note that [an NGram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20to%20victory%2Conto%20victory&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20to%20victory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Conto%20victory%3B%2Cc0) shows that to be a seldom-used construction, probably a solecism.

[image]

The sense of "onto victory" would seem to me to be not "moving toward victory" but "placing something on top of victory" which makes little sense (although one could argue for a metaphorical interpretation here, that is pretty strained and certainly not the most immediate and familiar potential usage).

Comment: I'm not sure why your final example needs care. Doesn't it fit with your  rule 1?  *"my sister's room"* is a noun phrase and a location.  Otherwise I agree with your answer.

Comment: There is also the element here of pairing *hold on* and *holding on*, which needs to be left as is. The Supremes said something similar, "You keep me hanging on," not onto.

Comment: So the battle cry "Onto victory!" is correct?

Comment: @chasly: The rule still applies. I just wanted to show the OP that if rephrasing the original one has to respect the change in circumstances. Probably I'm being overcautious, but you never know..

Comment: On reflection: I agree with @Hot Licks scepticism. "Onto victory" does not accord with your rule. As HL implies, it should be "On to victory!"

Comment: @chasly: I believe it would be better to say "On to victory!" You may want to reflect a little more on that. Also, an NGram search shows "onto victory" flatlining.

Comment: @HotLicks: See my edit.

Comment: So, moving onto the next topic ...

Comment: @ Robusto - You may like to read my comment again. But carefully this time  ;-)  -  P.S. If you are answering a comment, it is helpful to say whose comment, otherwise we have to read through them all and guess which you are referring to (I'm still not sure). Just a suggestion

Comment: @chasly: I think HL's comment was ambiguous. I'm not sure why he said that. You seemed to be agreeing with him. I don't think he was implying what you think he was. In any case, I did "@"-mention you where I was addressing you.

Comment: @Robusto - Okay. Wrt mentioning the commenter, I meant in your addendum where you just say *"A commenter below believes"*

Comment: @chasly: That was me being discreet. Also, "@"-mentions don't work in question and answer text.

Comment: @Robusto - Why be discreet? No-one has done anything criminal. I often answer comments as an edit and frequently disagree with them. It's part of the to-and-fro of academic discourse.  Whether or not the @ works is not really relevant. Just giving the commenter's name lets everyone know which comment you are addressing (otherwise why bother?)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. "Thank you for holding on to me when I did not want to hold on to
>    anyone."
> 2. "Thank you for holding onto me when I did not want to
>    hold onto anyone."

They are slightly different in that we could legitimately set part of the first one off with commas, or even parentheses i.e.

"Thank you for holding on (to me)  when I did not want to hold on to anyone."

This is possible because there are two distinct verbs

(1) [to hold](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold)

(2) [to hold on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hold-on)

This splitting is not possible with all verbs though because not all verbs have a [prepositional form](https://studyandexam.com/preposition3.html).

Example

(a) *He stepped onto the platform.* (correct)

(b) *He stepped on, to the platform.* (incorrect)

The second example is wrong because there is no prepositional verb "to step on" . You can use "step" with "on" but not as in sentence (b). For example , it is possible to say, *"He stepped on the cockroach".* (correct)